# How to load types in the System namespace with Mono.Cecil?

Tags: mono.cecil

I'm using Mono.Cecil (0.9.5.4) to inject code into some of my assemblies. Some of the calls I need to make are to objects in the System.ComponentModel namespace. How can I find those 'MethodReferences' that I need to call?

What I tried:

```
AssemblyDefinition assembly = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(dllPath);
var objectModelRef = assembly.MainModule.AssemblyReferences.First(i => i.Name == "System.ObjectModel")
var objectModelAssembly = assembly.MainModule.AssemblyResolver.Resolve(objectModelRef);
```

But then `objectmodelAssembly.MainModule.Types` has no actual types in it.

I also tried this:

```
AssemblyDefinition assembly = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(dllPath);
var system = new DefaultAssemblyResolver().Resolve("System");
var objectIWantToInject = assembly.MainModule.Import(FindType(...));
```

This works fine on a machine with the full .net 4.5 installed. But since my assembly is a PCL, when I try executing on WinPhone, I get FileNotFound for 'System'.

So if I wanted to get an instance of `TypeDefinition` for `System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs` that I could then make calls to some of the methods on, how would I?

Comment: Did you manage to get this solved in the end? I am running in to similar challenges.

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft I hate to be the one to do this; I did solve it but I don't remember how :( In the end we switched to https://github.com/Fody/Fody, which worked out of the box and got rid of the old code.

Comment: Shame on you for forgetting :)  I did eventually resolve it (pun intended - the type needs to be resolved for further inspection) - I will post it up as an answer for anyone in the future that may be struggling with the same.  As for Fody - I have taken a look but it seems like just another layer on top. That said, I think I may write a Fody plug-in for what I need and then leverage some of the other benefits it offers instead of crafting it all myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

```
    AssemblyDefinition assembly = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(dllPath);
    var system = new DefaultAssemblyResolver().Resolve("System");
    var objectIWantToInject = assembly.MainModule.Import(FindType(...));
```

I think you are missing at least one import, e.g.

```
 assembly.MainModule.Import(typeof(System.ObjectModel);
```

I believe you will also need to "Resolve" it to walk further down the tree.

Here is a working sample for anyone that is feeling the same pain:

```
    assembly.MainModule.Import(typeof(string));
    var methodBaseRef = assembly.MainModule.Import(typeof(System.Reflection.MethodBase));
    var getMemberInfo = assembly.MainModule.Import(typeof(System.Reflection.MemberInfo));
    var getMemberInfoResolver = getMemberInfo.Resolve();
    var getCurrentMethodRef = assembly.MainModule.Import(typeof(System.Reflection.MethodBase).GetMethod("GetCurrentMethod"));
    var get_DeclaringType = assembly.MainModule.Import(getMemberInfoResolver.Methods.Single(m => m.Name == "get_DeclaringType"));
    var getTypeInfo = assembly.MainModule.Import(typeof(Type));
    var name = assembly.MainModule.Import(typeof(Type).GetMethod("Name"));
```